# Visual Transformer - understand if a model is pre-trained or not

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, classification

I am working on a binary image classifier, and I am now testing using a Visual Transformer for the task. As a reference, I am using the [model reimplementation by lucidrains](https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch). In the code snippet used to declare the model (see [here](https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch#simple-vit) and below), is the model pretrained or do we do the training from scratch? Thanks!

```
import torch
from vit_pytorch import SimpleViT

v = SimpleViT(
    image_size = 256,
    patch_size = 32,
    num_classes = 1000,
    dim = 1024,
    depth = 6,
    heads = 16,
    mlp_dim = 2048
)
```

Comment: if you didn't load any weights... was this not implied by any teaching materials you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the [implementation code](https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch/blob/b3e90a265284ba4df00e19fe7a1fd97ba3e3c113/vit_pytorch/simple_vit.py#L81-L116), there is no weight loading involved.